# Why does the header in my html code randomly indent?

Tags: html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXJ5C.png)I am new to coding and html and I am having trouble with the second h3 line in my code on line 28. For some reason it wants to indent on the second header. I have included a screenshot of the code  and a picture of the resulting translated webpage. Is there someone with any insight as to why this is happening or someone who can point me in the right direction?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2OuN.png) Sorry for the dumb question, i'm still learning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pictures of code can not be copy and pasted. Put the html in the question. A good IDE with a linter attached would point out your errors.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Run it through http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 1):

You're missing another closing `</ul>` before the second `<h3>` header.